# HTML5 canvas toDataURL throws exception in IE

Tags: canvas, svg, todataurl

I'm trying to convert an SVG image created by Highcharts to a PNG image by drawing on canvas in order to be able to hand it over to htmlkit:

```
            function b64EncodeUnicode(str) {
                return btoa(encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g, function (match, p1) {
                    return String.fromCharCode('0x' + p1);
                }));
            }
            var svg = document.getElementsByClassName('highcharts-root')[0];
            var w = $(svg).width();
            var h = $(svg).height();
            var container = $(".highcharts-container").eq(0);
            var dataURL = "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + b64EncodeUnicode(container.html());

            // create PNG image by drawing on canvas
            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.width = w;
            canvas.height = h;
            img = new Image();
            img.onload = function () {
                canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(this, 0, 0);
                dataURL2 = canvas.toDataURL();  // this instruction throws an exception
                // some more code
            }
            img.src = dataURL;
```

This works fine in Opera, Firefox and Chrom but unfortunately in IE11 the last line throws a security exception. 
I found some discusssions regarding this issue, but none matched my problem und I could not find a solution.
I'm running the code on the local IIS sever of Webmatrix3.

Comment: What did say the discussions about it ? Something along the lines of "This is a security issue in IE<Edge, drawing any svg on a canvas will taint this canvas."? The only workaround is to use directly canvas API method to redraw entirely your svg. Some libraries like canvg do this for you. I'm pretty sure there are a lot of dupes.

Comment: 'Some libraries like canvg do this for you.' canvg works fine for me, thanks for this hint!